# Can a while clause be followed by the present perfect?

Tags: verbs, tenses, present-perfect

Is it correct to say the following?

> - While working on my project I have found an interesting research paper.

I mean whether *while* and the use of present perfect in the same sentence is correct.

Comment: Present perfect and *while* can certainly be used in the same sentence, but maybe not in your exact sentence. Why are your reasons for wanting to use present perfect rather than simple past?

Comment: This has a bit in common with [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/577882/how-should-i-interpret-this-sentence), in that "while working" can be understood to cover a broad period of time. I wonder whether your question is: can "while working" cover the past as well as the present? Yes, it would equate to "While [I **was**] working on...". You could even use it for future: "While working on my project I plan to..."

Comment: If it makes sense to say "I have found", it's fine to add the while clause. But these things depend on context.

Answer (score 2):

There is rarely good reason to make past or present perfect out of simple sentences. In my work I find people regularly bending over backwards to shoe-horn *having* or *have* into their descriptions. I tell people to avoid it except for meals; what are we having or what will we have to eat etc.

Is it English, yes. Is it correct, maybe just. Is it understandable, yes. Is it the way one should speak or write, no, it is possible but sounds strained and unnatural to a native speaker. Directness by way of simplicity is always the goal.

Comment: Well said and you found the right thing to say.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Still the question is whether Present Perfect is possible and sounds natural to native speakers here or Past Simple is the only possible Tense and then we should refer the whole sentence to the past. While if Iwant to speak about the project I am currently working on I should say just - Working on ... I have found

Comment: There are many cases where it's perfectly idiomatic to use present perfect, eg recounting experiences.

Comment: Thank you, Lambie. @TK  It can be/is understood as I said but is not always the easiest way to say it.

Answer (score -2):

By far you could use while in combination with present perfect, and it can even sound natively in formal English, but whether it is correct depends on great amount of semantical aspects.

While you have made minimal progress, it’s by no means the kind of progress that you need to make.

In the case above it can be traced that the sentence’s syntax depends straightforwardly on its semantics, so then it’s rather rational solution to use while+ present perfect than for example while + Simple past.

Comment: Whatever is "sound natively" even supposed to mean?  That doesn't sound formal, it sounds ungrammatical. You have to use predicate adjectives for such verbs, not adverbs of manner. Somebody unnatived you with wild abandon about how English really works.

Comment: Whatever you evaluate conversational English in this chat to be formal or native:) we are discussing the issue of while+ present perfect that you couldn’t have comprehended for about a year.